# How to iterate column values over the other column by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I want to use the values of the Z over the X column. But I want to work in this way: 0 index value of the Z column will be shifted to index 1 of the X column. I want to shift values from 1 to 100 index. For this task, I want to work with For-loop. How may I write the code?

**I am using pandas/python**

```
#Index X     Y    Z
#0   Non    Non  10
#1   Non    Non  20
#2   Non    Non  30
#3   Non    Non  40
#4   Non    Non  50
#5   Non    Non  60
#6   Non    Non  70
#7   Non    Non  80
#8   Non    Non  90
#9   Non    Non  100
#10  Non    Non  110
```

Comment: `df['X']  = df['Z'].shift(100)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df['X'] = df['Z'].shift(1)

      Index X       Y   Z
    0   0   NaN     NaN 10
    1   1   10.0    NaN 20
    2   2   20.0    NaN 30
    3   3   30.0    NaN 40
    4   4   40.0    NaN 50
    5   5   50.0    NaN 60
    6   6   60.0    NaN 70
    7   7   70.0    NaN 80
    8   8   80.0    NaN 90
    9   9   90.0    NaN 100
```

Here is the updated version ( update for the Y as well ):

```
 df['X'] = df['Z'].shift(1)
 df['Y'] = df['Z'].shift(2)


   Index    X   Y      Z
0   0    NaN    NaN    10
1   1   10.0    NaN    20
2   2   20.0    10.0    30
3   3   30.0    20.0    40
4   4   40.0    30.0    50
5   5   50.0    40.0    60
6   6   60.0    50.0    70
7   7   70.0    60.0    80
8   8   80.0    70.0    90
9   9   90.0    80.0    100
```

I am not able to understand why you are insisting on a for-loop solution for your requirement.  Here it is:

```
def update_X_Y(frame):
    for x in range(frame.shape[0]):
        frame.loc[x+1,'X'] = frame.loc[x,'Z']
        frame.loc[x+2,'Y'] = frame.loc[x,'Z']

## Calling the function:
update_X_Y(df)
```

I would not use for-loop.

Comment: It is possible to fill up the index o of X? because it is showing NaN.
My other question is like that, if I want to use the Z values for Y too [2nd index of Z] it can be possible to write code by looping format [for example i =, and then for loop] ??

Comment: You said  ** It is possible to fill up the index o of X? **   What do you want fill X[0]  with?    Is there any reason why you want to use for loops?    I will update my answer for your updated question.

Comment: Actually I am working for the dataset. In the data, there is 8000 index. After that, I added two additional columns X and Y. So I want to use the index value of Z. So are there any options to use for loop?

Comment: On your insistence I added a for-loop solution in my updated answer. I would not use this for-loop solution unless you have other compelling reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very kind of You

Comment: You are welcome.  I see you accepted other solution.  Did my loop solution work.

Comment: Yes both are wirking. Thanks a lot